# Using jQuery Ajax methods display a response from a PHP page?

Tags: php, ajax, jquery

I'm trying to implement the Jquery .ajax method to simplify the ajax in my website.

Here is the function I'm working with:

```
function autoComplete(q, succ)
{
    $.ajax({type:"GET",
        url: "search.php",
        data: "q="+q,
        success: succ
    }); 
}

$('input#auto_results').live('keyup', function() {

    var text = $('input#auto_results').val();       

    autoComplete(text,
        function(data) 
        { 

        alert(data);

        }); 
});
```

The response on the PHP page is simply:

```
echo "response";
```

So I figure that it should alert the response when the function is called, on 'keyup'.
Sadly, nothing occurs. I must be doing something wrong, I am just not sure what it is.

Comment: Have you checked firebug? Is the request sent, is data received? Are there any errors? Is the PHP page and the page containing this JS under same domain?

Comment: are there any JS errors? Using firebug or chrome dev tools can you see if the ajax request is being started?

Comment: try doing `alert("Response: '"+data+"'")` - this way you will at least be alerted when response is empty (otherwise empty alert doesn't open at all)

Comment: Thank you for that suggestion! please post as an answer

Comment: I checked and I made the mistake of thinking that the reference to the php page needed to be made from the folder where the JS file that makes the Ajax calls are. I just referenced to dir/search.php and it worked

Comment: glad you got it sorted :)  (deleted my answer)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

is "keyup" event firing? 
do following.

```
$('input#auto_results').live('keyup', function() {

    var text = $('input#auto_results').val();       
    alert("Keyup event is firing");
    autoComplete(text,
        function(data) 
        { 

        alert(data);

        }); 
});
```

if event is firing. then see firebug console tab

or put error function callback on your code:

```
function autoComplete(q, succ)
{
    $.ajax({type:"GET",
        url: "search.php",
        data: "q="+q,
        error:function(request, textStatus, err){
           alert(request.statusText);
        },
        success: succ
    }); 
}
```

you may get near to error.